# Multiplication with discrete delta function

Tags: dirac-delta, kronecker-delta, discrete-time

What would be the outcome of multiplying the delta function of discrete time with another function

> e.g.: δ(n-m)•y(n) =?

What would be the outcome of the multiplication between two different deltas?

> e.g.: δ(n)•δ(n-m)=?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're referring to the [Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) or the [discrete delta function $\delta(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/DiscreteDelta/introductions/TensorFunctions/ShowAll.html)defined as follows.

$$\delta(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & x=0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
\right.\tag{1}$$

---

The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is mostly useful in integrals such as the following.

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(n-m)\ y(n)\,dn=y(m),\quad m\in\mathbb{R}\tag{2}$$

$$\int_{-\infty }^\infty\delta(n)\ \delta(n-m)\,dn=\delta(m)\tag{3}$$

---

For the the discrete delta function:

$$\delta(n-m)\ y(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 y(n) & m=n \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
\right.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I am pretty sure I was referring to Dirac's delta function, but as I remember I found a solution to my problem back then. Thanks anyway for your answer!